# When creating a template class and adding an event is there any need to remove it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the code I have:

```
namespace X.Templates
{
    public class ABCTemplate : Grid
    {

        public ABCTemplate()
        {
            TapGestureRecognizer tap = new TapGestureRecognizer() { NumberOfTapsRequired = 1 };
            tap.Tapped += Tap_Tapped;
        }

        private void Tap_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Should I do anything to remove the Tap_Tapped or will it simply go away when the ABCTemplate is no longer used?

Comment: What does "remove the Tap_Tapped" mean?  Do you mean you do not need it in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any need to remove it ?

**EventHandler** is Managed resources  that will been cleaned up implicitly by the garbage collector(**GC**). You do not have to write code to release such resources explicitly .

So in your case, it is unnecessary to remove it manually as it will been released automatically when the parent view ending its' lifecycle (pop up from current page or remove from the page) .

Of course sometimes we will see the code like

```
tap.Tapped -= Tap_Tapped;
```

This is because of code standards . And if we invoke the code in a wrong will maybe let the Event don't work any more  .